# memory leak with shelve

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks, shelve

I'm using shelve to store data, mostly timestamp that I want to retrieve fast.

I've populated my shelve with 40000 random key to see how it goes.

```
dbfs = shelve.open(filePath)
for i in range(0, 40000):
    key = "OD452_TP3_{}".format(i)
    dbfs[key] = datetime.datetime.now()
dbfs.close()
```

It gives me a file of approx 6 Mo :

```
5971968 May 24 16:06 dbfs.bin
```

Then I remove everything in the file:

```
dbfs = shelve.open(filePath)
for key in dbfs:
    del dbfs[key]
dbfs.close()
```

And the file did not go back to zero but got bigger:

```
6606848 May 24 16:07 dbfs.bin
```

I kept repeating the same operation and, I see the same behaviour.
The memory is never released, and when I delete all entries I can an extra memory usage of approx 10%...

I was about to shelve all across my platform to manage timestamp, but I can't have this behaviour.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Julien

Comment: That's actually pretty normal behavior - it depends on the actual engine used by shelve. Your question was asked in the past - https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-November/260572.html

Comment: ok I see. thanks. Would you know anything else I could use that don't have this behaviour ? I just need to store timestamp (about 10.000) and refresh them often. I guess sqlite would be an overkill

Comment: I cannot see why you can't use shelve for that - new keys will take place of old ones, so the file will not grow anymore.

Comment: Are you sure ? I tried removing entries and then readding and the file kept increasing. a good workaround would be tp monitor the size of the file and then transfer all my 'active' keys in a new file above a certain threshold.